# Laravel 7: How to search with json data?

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, laravel-7

In my product table brand column values save like this with json format `["63","64"]`
A product can have multiple brand name. When I will select a brand name it will show all the products under that brand name.

For single brand name, the search working. But for my case, How can I make it workable?

My controller:

```
$products = ProductStock::join('products','product_stocks.product_id', '=', 'products.id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('published', '1')->select('products.*','product_stocks.id as stock_id','product_stocks.variant','product_stocks.price as stock_price', 'product_stocks.qty as stock_qty', 'product_stocks.image as stock_image')->orderBy('products.created_at', 'desc');
    
if($request->brand != null){
   $products = $products->where('products.brand_id', $request->brand);
 }
```

How can I search products with brand_id here?

Comment: Don't put values like `["63","64"]` for `brand_id`. Like you said, this will work for single values, but not for multiple. You should split this to a pivot table, like `brand_product`, with `product_id` and `brand_id`, and properly define your relationship as a `many-to-many`. Check Laravel's documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: I want to see all the products under selected brand. And in product table, brand id column values are like this ["63","64"], that means this products belongs to 63 and 64 brands. So when I will search with a single brand id it will match all the products and show matched products only.

Comment: A single product can have one brand id or multiple.

Comment: I'm aware, but right now, you'll need custom logic to query for IDs 63 and 64. If you bother to read my comment, you'll see I'm suggesting to refactor your database to a normalized `many-to-many`, then you'll be able to do this _much_ easier. I don't have an answer for your custom requirements, you'll have to see if someone else wants to do that for you, or you can attempt to fix your setup.

Comment: You must use attribute casting.
I already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74442090/8509638