# i want to convert my laravel select query with update query

Tags: php, laravel

This is my query:

```php
$data = Collections::select(DB:raw("REGEXP_REPLACE(tour_id,'(,2|2,|2)','') as `new_tour_id"))->get();
```

I want to convert this query to update all my records in the database.
This is my database table shows:
[image]

I want this result:
[image]

Comment: Your data is structured very badly. You should define a proper [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship between collections and tours using a pivot table otherwise your data will quickly become unmanageable.

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 5.x allows attribute casting so it's possible to cast attributes to another data type for converting on runtime.
In this case, just declare a protected $casts property for example:

```
protected $casts = [
    'tour_id' => 'array', // Will converted to (Array)
];
```

then store your ids like this

[image]

and finally search like this :

```
->whereJsonContains('tour_id', 3)->update([...]);
```

read more :
[JSON Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#json-where-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a model for this table as `Tour` what you have to do is this:

```
$tours = Tour::select('tour_id')

foreach($tours as $tour) {
    $tour->update([
        tour_id = $whatever_id_to_update
    ]);
}
```